# How to achieve symbol referencing across directories in vim?

Tags: c, vim, project

Can *ctags* tag symbols from a directory up in the hierarchy also or is it limited to create tags for current and sub-directories only?

Basically I'm looking for Visual Studio like symbol cross referencing it is very helpful in understanding alien source code flow.

If not Vim, then which other editor should I use?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ctags only recurses to subdirectories. But all you have to do is run `ctags -R .` in your project home directory, and it will create a `tags` file for your whole project.

Comment: yes thats correct but when i open a file say proj/dir1/def.c and press ctrl+] on a function name which is defined say in proj/dir2/abc.c, I get tag not found :(

Comment: ctags generates relative path names. So your current directory in vim should be `proj` in order for the tags file to point to the correct files. Perhaps you could write a script to adjust the contents of the `tags` file to point to absolute path names, but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't limited to specifying one tags file in Vim.  This is an alternative to the other answers; you can just do something like:

```
set tags=tags,~/wintags,c:/path/to/moretags/etc
```

So you don't need to take the time regenerating a monolithic tags file when you just want to update your local tags.

Regarding the OP's comment in another answer,

> yes thats correct but when i open a file say proj/dir1/def.c and press ctrl+] on a function name which is defined say in proj/dir2/abc.c, I get tag not found :(

You could also create one tags file for all of your projects at the 'proj' root:

```
set tags=tags;c:/path/to/proj
```

This will use the first file named `tags` that it finds as it walks up the directory hierarchy from where you are.

You can combine these two techniques to have a project-local tags file and then a "global" tags file that isn't updated as often.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it's got similar user interface for asking it to do it's thing, so you need to actually specify "go down directories", I find that `cscope` is a very nice tool, whcih does everything that ctags does and a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

ctags (well, exctags at least) can create tags for as many directory trees you want. Simply run

```
exctags -R dir1 dir2 ...
```

Then vim knows about all the symbols you need. For example, one of the directories could be `/usr/include` in addition to your own source directory.

Make sure to run `vim path/to/file.c` from the same directory you created the `tags` file in.